# Updating VirtualBox Additions ISO

Tags: virtualbox

In just the past few days all my VM's started complaining that I need to update my VirtualBox Additions ISO. Everytime I click download, it fails at the end with a 'network error'. I tried this on several different networks.

Has anyone experienced this and/or knows how to fix it? I can always download them manually, but that won't stop the popup everytime I start a VM, and honestly this should work. I'm thinking, it's probably a permissions issue wherever it's trying to store the ISO, but I have no idea where that is.

Comment: You don't need to download anything. Just install Guest Additions from machine menu.

Comment: And the question is vague. Is the question related to Ubuntu? What is the host and the guest OS?